# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils'

Tags: python

I am getting the exception when I am installing the below package in python.

```
pip install django_microsoft_auth
```

Exception

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils'
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved it with the below option.

**Linux**

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

**Windows**

```
set SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

After that, I have executed the pip install command.

```
pip install django_microsoft_auth
```

This is the bug in setuptools. See *[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils' #2353](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2353)*.

Comment: Had this error on a laptop running Lubuntu 18.04, this solution fixed it

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in setuptools; see *[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools._distutils' #2353](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2353)*

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-distutils
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.